# Google Cloud Debugger for Python App Engine module says "Deployment revision unknown"

Tags: google-app-engine, google-app-engine-python, google-cloud-debugger

I'm trying to get the Google Cloud Debugger to work on my Python App Engine module. I've followed the instructions and:

1. Connected to my Bitbucket hosted repository.
2. Generated the `source-context.json` and `source-contexts.json` using `gcloud preview app gen-repo-info-file`
3. Uploaded using `appcfg.py update`

However when I try to set a snapshot using the console, there is message saying:

> The selected debug target does not have source revision information. The source shown here may not match the deployed source.

And when I try to set the snapshot point, I get the error:

> Failed to update the snapshot

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you did everything correctly.

The "Failed to update the snapshot" error shows up when there is some problem on the Cloud Debugger backend. Please contact the Cloud Debugger team through cdbg-feedback@google.com or submit feedback report in Google Developer Console.