# Does Google Cloud Debugger require that source files be placed in a specific locations in the repository?

Tags: google-app-engine, google-app-engine-python, google-cloud-debugger

I'm trying to setup Cloud Debugging for a Python App Engine module without success. See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35090793/google-cloud-debugger-for-python-app-engine-module-says-deployment-revision-unk) for the specific issue I am having.

I am wondering if the reason for my issue is the locations of the source files in my repository.

My source files are (for various reasons) in rather idiosyncratic locations and I have a "build" step that copies the files into into a staging directory where everything is laid out as app engine expects. It also generates some files (including the app.yaml) based on configuration settings.

I then run `appcfg.py update` from this staging directory.

Given all this moving around of files, I am wondering how the Cloud Debugger can identify which source file in the module I uploaded corresponds to which file in the repository. Is it designed to look in a specific locations (which will explain my problem), or is it somehow more robust than that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think the issue is related to location of source files in the repository.

The Python Cloud Debugger loops through all the loaded modules and tries to find the best match. The actual location of the module only matters if there are multiple modules with the same name. In this case, the debugger will try to find the best match given the relative path of the files in the repository. You can see the implementation [here](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/cloud-debug-python/blob/master/src/googleclouddebugger/module_lookup.py).

Comment: Took me a little while to realize you meant Python modules and not App Engine modules. The implementation was really helpful in understanding how everything worked. Thanks!

Comment: Thanks for the clarification. Yes, I meant Python modules.